# Why is the table view not resetting the results after the cancel button is clicked?

Tags: swift

When the user types something into the ***searchBar*** the results are updated in my ***tableView***.  When the user cancels the search in the ***searchBar*** the results are resetting. But when the user wants to cancel the search outside of the search bar the ***tableView*** is not resetting and keeps the input.
I made a [gif](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/fVsbTwlaiNWNERjF92) to show my problem.

And [here](https://pastebin.com/0trewzFk) is the full source code for the class.

---

```
var searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar()

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBarText = searchBar.text?.lowercased()
        searchBarScope = searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        showList()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.text = ""
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    public func setupSearchBarStyle() {
        UISearchBar.appearance().searchBarStyle = .minimal
        UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        if (navigationItem.title != nil) {
            self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [String(format: "gesamte %@", ci("project_s")),  String(format: "in %@", navigationItem.title!)]
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)


        navigationItem.title = navigationItem.title ?? ci("plan_p")

        guard let projectId = GlobalState.selectedProjectId, let byProject : Results<Structure> = self.by(projectId: projectId) else {
            return
        }

        //search bar
        tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchBar.delegate = self

        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

---

When the user cancels the search outside of the ***searchBar*** the table view should be reseted.

Comment: It is not clear how you are hiding/removing the `searchBar` and i think you need to call `showList()` after that.

Comment: I set the initial state of the ***searchBar*** to the default state in my ***searchBarTextDidEndEditing()*** function

Comment: @Nimrani1337 Do you press cancel in your gif? What do you mean "cancels the search outside of the searchBar".

Comment: Yes It is not obvious in the gif. I press "Abbrechen" ( it means Cancel ).

Comment: @Nimrani1337 reload tableview in "searchBarCancelButtonClicked"

Comment: Does not work. If I press "Abbrechen" (="Cancel") it only shows the last thing the user typed in the search bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the thing you are looking for. But if you want to reset your data when the user touches outside the `searchBar` you can try this.

```
    func resetData()
    {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(loadData))

        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func loadData()
    {
        //The code to reset
    }
```

Also in your `viewDidLoad()` : `resetData()`

But I don't thing that this is the right approach. This code is to do something if the user taps. I don't think that you want to reset your data if the user does that.